# Currently running Magento 1.9.3.7 and would like to update to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento1.9.3.7

Currently running Magento 1.9.3.7 and would like to update to Magento 2

Do I have to start from scratch with Magento 2? Also, how do I use the setup wizard to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes - if your current magento version is 1.9.3.7 - then yes you need to start with from scratch !!**

As both version of Magento have huge difference.

If you wanted to install Magento 2 - Below i am sharing two links which is self explanatory for how to install magento 2 with step by step :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-install-magento-2-on-localhost-via-xampp/

I also assume as you have current magento version is 1.9.3.7 so letter on you required to migrate your existing Magento version data to Magento 2 .

So for that Magento have developed Data migration tool - using that you can easily move your data from Magento 1 to Magento 2

**Below i am sharing link for Data Migration Tool as well :**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Over there its explained - how to install Magento data migration tool and how we can transfer data from magento 1 to Magento 2 .

Hope it helps !!